# I cannot start Apache and MySQL in XAMPP

Tags: xampp, localhost

I installed XAMPP two days ago on Windows 11, this is for local development of Magento.
Today when I press Start for Apache and MySQL, I cannot start it.
It gave me the prompt that

```
Status change detected: running, and immediately Status change detected: stopped.
And then returned with a few lines of error: 
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
If you need more help, copy and post this
entire log window on the forums
```

For Apache and MySQL, the error information is the same.
I just installed it two days ago, and did not change anything.

I tried to find answer on Stack Overflow, but did not find. I did not change port. As I am in China, I use VPN for internet connection, but I didn't change anything like VPN line.

I really need help.
Thanks!
[image]

Comment: There are instructions here to find out if other application using the port 80 (neede by Apache). If so, you get this sort of message.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77028983/my-laptop-is-having-issues-starting-apache-on-the-xampp-control-panel-i-changed/77434525#77434525