# My laptop is having issues starting Apache on the xampp control panel. I changed ports to 8080 and 4433 but it doesn't work

Tags: apache, http, xampp, notepad

This problem occurred when I downloaded something.

This shows: httpd.conf and httpd-ssl.conf file.

The other options that I seen for config are httpd-xampp.conf, php.ini and config.inc.php (I didn't include these in this comment. I changed the ports, I think something is using port 80 but I don't know how to check.

Apache PID(s) that were shown are: 21080, 1440

Apache port(s): 4433, 8080

```
16:26:02  [Apache]  Problem detected!
16:26:02  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
16:26:02  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
16:26:02  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
16:26:02  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
16:26:02  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache app...
16:26:02  [Apache]  Status change detected: running
```

The changes I made to httpd.conf:

```
Listen 12.34.56.78:8080
Listen 8080
ServerName localhost:8080`
```

The changes I made to httpd.conf httpd-ssl.conf:

```
Listen 4433

<VirtualHost _default_:4433>
```

I just want Apache to work I am stressed out because it's not starting up even after I changed the ports, I think something is using port 80 but I don't know how to check.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, you can check which ports are in use by using the `netstat` command, shown below. [(More info)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/netstat)

Open Command Prompt in administrator mode by searching for it in the Windows search bar and clicking 'Run as Administrator'. Then run the following command

```
netstat -ab
```

If you're on Linux, you can use the `lsof` command, shown below. [(More info)](https://www.howtogeek.com/426031/how-to-use-the-linux-lsof-command/#displaying-files-associated-with-internet-connections-and-ports).

Open the linux terminal (assuming you have a GUI loaded, if not just type in the command directly) and type in the following command:

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n
```

That's how you find out which processes are using which ports, if that is the issue you're facing

Comment: These are the active locations:
[OneDrive.exe]
  TCP    [::]:80                LAPTOP-DOMLS00U:0      LISTENING,
Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7680           LAPTOP-DOMLS00U:0      LISTENING,

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             LAPTOP-DOMLS00U:0      LISTENING.

(not sure what it means but it probably means some other app is using the port. Don't know what to do next....)

Comment: @RobbieSobbie what you could try is changing the port that Apache runs on to one that doesn't appear in use by other apps (checking using the commands above). I'll do a bit of testing with Apache myself to see if there's any other causes of this issue though because I've not used Apache in a bit

Answer (score 0):

If you enlarge your Xampp Control Panel window, you will see on the extreme right of it, a button called "Netstat". It will give you the same information as DOS command netstat, but in a "beginners-readable" format. There, you must inspect the second column (port) for the number 80. After finding it, go to the fourth column (Name) and you will see the application that is using this port. Copy its name and then search the internet to find out who is it.

Example: if you find that the executable Skype.exe is using port 80, searching the Internet you will discover that it refers to the application "Microsoft Skype".